# weird VBA presentation.close runtime error #91

Tags: vba, runtime, powerpoint

Open Powerpoint and ran this code at the first time, every was OK
but ran it at the second time, system threw `runtime error 91` and highlighted `oPres.Close`

I shutdowned powerpoint completely and ran it again, the first round is OK but the second round occurred error.

i am a little bit confused .

```
  Sub PrintAll()

Dim CurrentFolder As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim myPath As String
Dim myPath2 As String
Dim UniqueName As Boolean
Dim PDFName As String

Dim strCurrentFile As String
Dim strFileSpec As String

Dim sldTemp As Slide
Dim lngTemp As Long
Dim lngCount As Long

Dim PP As Object
Dim oPres As Object


    CurrentFolder = ActivePresentation.Path & "\" 'get current folder
    strFileSpec = "*.ppt"
    strCurrentFile = Dir$(CurrentFolder & strFileSpec)  

FileName = Mid(strCurrentFile, InStrRev(strCurrentFile, "\") + 1, _
   InStrRev(strCurrentFile, ".") - InStrRev(strCurrentFile, "\") - 1)  
     Debug.Print "FileName: " + FileName

     PDFName = CurrentFolder & FileName & ".pdf"    
     Debug.Print "PDFName: " + PDFName
     Set PP = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application") ' Late binding  

'-----------------------------------------Start Loop-----------------------------------------

While strCurrentFile <> ""

    On Error Resume Next

    Set oPres = PP.Presentations.Open(CurrentFolder & strCurrentFile)  

          Debug.Print "CurrentFolder: " + strCurrentFile

          If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Debug.Print "Unable to open " & FileName
          End If

    FileName = Mid(strCurrentFile, InStrRev(strCurrentFile, "\") + 1, _
     InStrRev(strCurrentFile, ".") - InStrRev(strCurrentFile, "\") - 1)   
    Debug.Print "FileName: " + FileName

    PDFName = CurrentFolder & FileName & ".pdf"    

    Debug.Print "PDFName: " + PDFName

    On Error GoTo 0


oPres.Close   'The 91 error occurred  here 


  strCurrentFile = Dir()  
Wend

'-----------------------------------------End Loop-----------------------------------------

PP.Quit  
Set PP = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next` becuase of that you will not come to know if powerpoint was able to open a file or not. Alternatively (Which I do not recommend) you can bypass that error by changing `oPres.Close` to `If Not oPres is Nothing then oPres.Close`

Answer (score 0):

thank you Siddharth.
I think i got the root cause: new version of powerpoint protection method will generate a temp copy for each PPT file closed without saving. and popup a dialog in the next time you open the same PPT file.

Resolution: add "oPres.Save" before close.